# In a pandas pivot table, how do I define a function for a subset of data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, user-defined-functions

I'm working with a dataframe similar to this:

| Name | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0.10 | 5.00 | Canada |
| Jane | 0.50 |  | Canada |
| Jack | 2.00 |  | Canada |
| Polly | 0.30 |  | Canada |
| Mike |  |  | Canada |
| Steve |  |  | Canada |
| Lily | 0.15 | 1.20 | Canada |
| Kate | 3.00 |  | Canada |
| Edward | 0.05 |  | Canada |
| Pete | 0.02 | 0.03 | Canada |

I am trying to define a function that will calculate the percentage of metrics that are greater than 1 *of the rows that have metrics*. I expect that for Metric 1, I should get 25%, and for Metric 2, I should get 66%. However, my function is returning results based on the total number of rows. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data_to_load['metric data.csv']))

df = df.fillna(0)

def metricgreaterthanone(x):
  return (x>1).sum()/len(x!=0)

pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Country'],values=["Name","Metric 1","Metric 2"],aggfunc={'Name':pd.Series.nunique, "Metric 1":metricgreaterthanone,"Metric 2":metricgreaterthanone})
```

The result I get is:

| Country | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | 0.2 | 0.2 | 10 |

So the function is returning the percent of all rows all that are greater than 1. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have empty string `""` instead of numbers. You can try:

```
def metricgreaterthanone(x):
    n = pd.to_numeric(x, errors="coerce")
    return (n > 1).sum() / n.notna().sum()


x = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=["Country"],
    values=["Name", "Metric 1", "Metric 2"],
    aggfunc={
        "Name": pd.Series.nunique,
        "Metric 1": metricgreaterthanone,
        "Metric 2": metricgreaterthanone,
    },
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
         Metric 1  Metric 2  Name
Country                          
Canada       0.25  0.666667    10
```

Answer (score 1):

`x!=0` returns a boolean array, so `len()` is not counting the number of Trues.

Try

```
def metricgreaterthanone(x):
  return (x>1).sum()/(x!=0).sum()
```